# How to get total member count of any Discord server?

Tags: api, axios, discord, puppeteer

I'm trying to build a scraping script to get a bunch of Discord server's total members. I actually did that with Puppeteer like below but I think my IP address has been banned because I'm getting "Invite Invalid" error from Discord even though invite links are working.

My question is that does Discord have APIs to get any server's total member count? Or is there any 3rd party library for that purpose? Or any other method?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const discordMembers = async ({ server, browser }) => {
  if (!server) return

  let totalMembers

  const page = await browser.newPage()

  try {
    await page.goto(`https://discord.com/invite/${server}`, {
      timeout: 3000
    })

    const selector = '.pill-qMtBTq'
    await page.waitForSelector(selector, {
      timeout: 3000
    })
    const totalMembersContent = await page.evaluate(selector => {
      return document.querySelectorAll(selector)[1].textContent
    }, selector)

    if (totalMembersContent) {
      totalMembers = totalMembersContent
        .replace(/ Members/, '')
        .replace(/,/g, '')
      totalMembers = parseInt(totalMembers)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }

  await page.close()

  if (totalMembers) return totalMembers
}

const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    await callback(array[i], i, array)
  }
}

const run = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  })

  const servers = ['tQp4pSE', '3P5K3dzgdB']

  await asyncForEach(servers, async server => {
    const members = await discordMembers({ server, browser })
    console.log({ server, members })

    // result
    // { server: 'tQp4pSE', members: 57600 }
    // { server: '3P5K3dzgdB', members: 159106 }
  })

  await browser.close()
}

run()
```

Update: Mar 22, 2022

Thanks for @Vaviloff's answer we can actually access Discord's private APIs but the problem is it's only accessible over browser. I'm getting `Request failed with status code 400` issue from Axios. Is it a CORS issue? How do we get the results in a Node.js app?

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const discordMembers = async ({ server }) => {
  try {
    const apiResult = await axios({
      data: {},
      method: 'get',
      url: `https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/${server}?with_counts=true&with_expiration=true`
    })
    console.log(apiResult)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

discordMembers({ server: 'tQp4pSE' })
```

Comment: how do you get a list of server's? i.e. is there a source to get all the valid invite codes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A lot of modern web applications have their own internal APIs. Oftentimes you can spot frontend making requests to it, by using Networking tab in Devtools (filter by Fetch/XHR type):

[image: internal API requests image]

Such API endpoints can change any time of course, but usually the last for a long time and is a rather convenient way of scraping

Currently Discord uses this URL for basic instance description:

```
https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/tQp4pSE?with_counts=true&with_expiration=true
```

By accessing it you get the desired data:
[image: Discord instance stats from internal API]

---

**Update**
To make your code work don't send any data in the request:

```
const apiResult = await axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: `https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/${server}?with_counts=true&with_expiration=true`
})
```

Comment: That's so great. Yeah it's more efficient than scraping.

Comment: Private API URL works nice on the browser but I'm getting `400 Bad Request` error in Node.js app. Is there any way that I could pull this off with Axios? I've also updated the question with the code I'm using. Also here's a RunKit link for you to try. https://runkit.com/6239bbb8c1f5520008c73880/6239bbca97a33100089e92fa

Comment: Sure, see the update

Comment: Looks like it's working except this time I'm getting `429 Too Many Requests` issue. I'm basically stuck at this point. Not sure what to do. Do you have any suggestions? Things come to my mind are I can set up a tor client and connect Discord over Tor network or maybe I could look for some proxy APIs. If I had to spin up a new server they'll probably ban that IP too. So new IP each time might the only way I guess.

Comment: Yup, if you're using a shared IP or just make way too many requests, be sure to rotate several proxies, that should do it.

Comment: Thank you for making me realize it might be the shared IP. Because I make 1 request per minute and close to 1K calls a day. It shouldn't get 429 error. I've tried finding proxy IPs but non of the free ones look like working so probably the best way is to make the calls over Tor network. I'll add an answer to this question if I finally make successful calls without getting banned.

Comment: 1 request per minute is waay too little to get banned by Discord, IMO. But could be bad reputation of the shared IP, yeah. As for the question itself didn't we find out how to get member count? =)

Comment: Another suggestion: where will you run the script? Maybe get a cloud VPS from the likes of Digital Ocean, Linode, Hetzner or Vultr and deploy there? You can recteate a server a few times until you find a clean working IP.

Comment: It's running on Digital Ocean. I was also thinking to set up a new server so yeah I'll try that.